# Sending ID to php via load function

Tags: php, javascript

I have the below javascript function and php file. I want to take the id in the URL and send it to PHP so that I can query the data by the particular ID on the page.  Here is what I have so far.  Let me know what needs to be changed in order to get this to work.  Thanks

javascript:

```
/*adding data*/
dhx.ready(function () {
    dhx.ui.fullScreen();
    dhx.ui({
        view: "scheduler",
        id: "scheduler"
    });
    $$("scheduler").load("placevents.php?id=" + getID, "scheduler");

    /*preselects Month view*/
    $$("scheduler").$$("month").show();
    $$("scheduler").$$("buttons").setValue("month");
});
```

PHP:

```
//Retrieve logged in user
$test = ".@$_REQUEST['id']";

$scheduler = new schedulerConnector( $res, "MySQL" );
$scheduler -> enable_log( "log.txt", true );
$scheduler -> render_table("events LEFT JOIN tblfollowers ON events.id_user = tblfollowers.username"
        . " WHERE events.status = 'active' AND((events.id_user) ='$test')"
        . " GROUP BY events.event_id, events.event_name, events.user_name, events.id_user, events.time, events.details, events.location, events.dresscode"
        . " Order By events.timestamp DESC","event_id","start_date, start_date,event_name,details");
$scheduler -> render_sql("select event_id, start_date, end_date, event_name, details from events ");
```

Comment: `$test = ".@$_REQUEST['id']";` is incorrect. the quotes in the array key will be spitting out syntax warnings, and whole thing looks like an [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) waiting to happen

Comment: ok, so how do I fix it?

Comment: What is `dhx`? What is `$$`? What actually happens when you run that code? Do you get errors in the browser console, or PHP errors, or database errors?

Comment: ok everything works fine except passing the id in the url to the php file.  thats basically the crux of the problem. How would I code that java where it says .load("placevents.php to include the id in the url here?

Answer (score 0):

Please post full source code, however I think that there are two error
first you must modify this:

```
$test = ".@$_REQUEST['id']";
```

Into this:

```
$test = $_REQUEST['id'];
mysql_real_escape_string($test);
```

This help you to prevent sql injection.

And as I say above I don't know you source code but I think that there are an other error:

```
$$("scheduler").load("placevents.php?id=" + getID, "scheduler");
```

Try to modify it into this:

```
$$("scheduler").load("placevents.php?id=" + getID + "&scheduler");
```